# Creating an Azure Playlist

Tags: azure, playlist, azure-media-services

I am a college student doing work study in the marketing department. The new accessibility laws require all videos to be close captioned. My college decided to use Azure Media Player (AMP) to accomplish the captioning. My next task is to put the newly captioned videos back on our website. There are around 20 videos so a playlist is necessary. I cannot believe that Azure does not have or support playlists! That seems like something that would be included by default in ANY type of media player.

We previously used JW Player but it won't let you close caption. Azure does but won't let you use a playlist. Can anyone help me with a work-around? Is there any other media player that might work WITH the videos I've captioned, encoded, etc. in Azure? I've read that some "simple JavaScript" can add a playlist to Azure, but my skill set isn't at the point of writing my own JS work-around. Is anyone using one that they would be willing to share the code with me? We use SharePoint for the site's CMS.

ANY and ALL advice is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Noah. Can you share more detail on what you're looking for when you say playlist? Are you hosting these videos on SharePoint? Do you simply want to expose a way for users to select one of the different videos and render the video in Azure Media Player? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the JS needed to support a playlist is not exactly a workaround, rather it's to write a plugin to customize your player experience. Here's a basic example of a playlist you can play around with: sr-test.azurewebsites.net/Plugins/Playlists/example/index_update.html

it's a rough first iteration but will be up in the Azure Media Player plugin gallery soon.

If the playlist functionality is something you're looking for baked directly into the player, you can help us prioritize this work by voting on it as an idea in our userforum: aka.ms/ampuservoice
Feel free to email me directly if you have any more questions: saraje@microsoft.com